# Using boost spirit expression

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a problem with boost spirit expression.The original code is more complicated and I made a small snapshot of it.
This code works as expected in debug mode and doesn't in release, parse returns false, but should return true ( I'm testing it on Visual Studio 2019)

```
int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    auto X19 = qi::lit("                   ") | qi::lit(" 0.000000000000D+00");
    auto i4 = qi::uint_;
    string str = "1234                   1234";
    auto f = str.cbegin();
    auto l = str.cend();
    bool ret = qi::parse(f, l, ( i4 >> X19 >> i4 ));
}
```

The next snapshot works well in both modes:

```
int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    auto i4 = qi::uint_;
    string str = "1234                   1234";
    auto f = str.cbegin();
    auto l = str.cend();
    bool ret = qi::parse(f, l, ( i4 >> (qi::lit("                   ") | qi::lit(" 0.000000000000D+00")) >> i4 ));
    cout << ret << endl;
    return ret;
}
```

What I do wrong, dividing long expression this way ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran headlong into the the dangling temporaries trap with Spirit's Proto expressions. The short rule is:

> Don't use `auto` with Spirit expressions

Your program exhibits [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):  see it [Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YfTEone8T)

[image]

---

The workarounds involve `BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO` or `qi::copy` (which used to be available only as `boost::proto::deep_copy` before recent boost releases).

### Fixed

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b036d7faf88c2926)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    auto i4 = qi::copy(qi::uint_);
    auto X19 = qi::copy(               //
          qi::lit("                   ") //
        | qi::lit(" 0.000000000000D+00")//
        );

    std::string str = "1234                   1234";
    auto        f = str.cbegin(), l = str.cend();

    bool ret = qi::parse(f, l, (i4 >> X19 >> i4));
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ret << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
true
```

### BONUS

1. Note that Spirit X3 no longer has this restriction/problem: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f67644018684dc0)**

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

   int main() {
       namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

       auto i4 = x3::uint_;
       auto X19 =                           //
           x3::lit("                   ")   //
           | x3::lit(" 0.000000000000D+00") //
           ;

       std::string str = "1234                   1234";
       auto        f = str.cbegin(), l = str.cend();

       bool ret = parse(f, l, (i4 >> X19 >> i4));
       std::cout << std::boolalpha << ret << "\n";
   }
   ```
2. You might actually want

   ```
   qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 4, 4> i4;
   // or
   x3::uint_parser<int, 10, 4, 4> i4;
   ```
3. It looks a lot as if you're parsing COBOL like (fixed-width) records, in which case I think there are much better ways to organize your grammar to make it reliable.

Comment: Added 3 bonus notes

Comment: Added -fsanitize=address output live on Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/z/KhGeaGK8j

Comment: Thank you very much and yes, the original code was like that and I had to write custom parser for real numbers which checks both the whole lenght and the number of digits in the fraction part,  I haven't found how to do it.

Have I missed something in docs, where it's written about "auto" and "copy" ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask that as a separate question

Comment: I spent a small hour creating this as a starting point: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/462f73b9f43aeff6 So it would probably be very helpful to others if you asked this particular question :)

Comment: Made it now parse the sign in the policy, removing the semantic actions (and in fact any Phoenix use): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/041eb8e83adab87f

Comment: thank you, your solution is smaller than mine
and I created the question

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the question according to SO standards. And just posted an answer.